# sqlite: sum time over 24h to HHH:MM:SS

Tags: sqlite, time, sum

http://i1345.photobucket.com/albums/p668/Muufley/datacount_zpslqz6ho3i.jpg

This is a snapshot of my query result. This is the query I used:

```
SELECT time(sum(strftime('%s', time(TRACKTIME, 'unixepoch')) 
                   - strftime('%s', '00:00:00')), 'unixepoch') AS timesum, 
sum(TRACKTIME) AS timesumsec, ARTIST 
FROM playcount GROUP BY ARTISTID ORDER BY timesumsec DESC
```

It's for an sqlite database that collects track length in seconds of music artists. The query sums the total amount of seconds and then converts them to HH:MM:SS. The problem here is once it surpasses the 24h mark (86400 sec) the timesum column zeros the hour value. Ideally I'm trying to display HHH:MM:SS or D HH:MM:SS.